# Repeating variable in group by category in R

Tags: r

I have data for which I would like to create a new variable: **flag**
Data is set in a longitudinal format with repetition of id and have associated dates.

The other two important variables are **category and company**.
**Category:** for each id there will be at least one category **"a"** and **"b"**, but most of the times there will be multiple "a" and "b".
**Company:** There could be multiple company for the same ids. Sometime category "b" would have the same company as category "a" for a particular id.
Here for ease I have included only three company as x, y, z.

**I want to create a flag. So that when group_by id**

1. if there is at least one instance of same company launching product in category "b" and "a". Then flag the **"a"** with same product as **"rp"** (repeating product)*.
2. If not, than flag all the corresponding "a" as **"nr"** (no repeating product in b).
3. For the "b" if there is a corresponding "rp". I want to sequence all the "b" with same company as "a" based on date such as **p1, p2, p3,...** (if the date of product for same then it could be p1, p1, p2,..), and for the remaining "b" with no same company as **"p0"**
4. For the "b" with corresponding "a" as "nr" we can again call them as **"p0"**

**Below is the data frame with the flag variable(expected output)**

```
id<- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5)
date<- as.Date(c("2001-01-04", "2007-09-23", "2008-11-14",
                 "2009-11-13", "2012-07-21", "2014-09-15",
                 "2000-04-01", "2008-07-14", "2008-07-14", 
                 "2001-03-21", "2019-05-23", "2019-05-08", 
                 "2004-07-06", "2007-08-12", "2011-09-20", 
                 "2011-09-20", "2014-08-15", "2014-08-15"))
category<- c("a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b",
           "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
company<-c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "x", "x",
           "x", "y", "z", "x", "x", "x", "x",  "x", "y")
flag<-c ("rp","p1", "p2", "nr", "p0", "p0", "rp", "p1",
         "p1", "nr", "p0", "p0", "rp", "rp", "p1", "p1", 
         "p2", "p0")
dfx <- data.frame(id, date, category, company, flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach with `tidyverse`, if I understand the logic correctly. After grouping by both `id` and `company`, you can see if both categories "a" and "b" are present; if so, mark those rows where category is "a" with "rp".

A more convoluted `case_when` can consider your different rules, but leave as missing `NA` situations where you need "p" with a sequence of numbers. A temporary column including a counter can be made based on these missing values to give you "p1", "p2", etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfx %>%
  group_by(id, company) %>%
  mutate(new_flag = case_when(
    all(c("a", "b") %in% category) & category == "a" ~ "rp",
    category == "a" ~ "nr",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new_flag = case_when(
    category == "b" & new_flag[category == "a"][1] == "nr" ~ "p0", 
    category == "b" & new_flag[category == "a"][1] == "rp" &
      company == company[category == "a"][1] ~ NA_character_,
    category == "b" & new_flag[category == "a"][1] == "rp" &
      company != company[category == "a"][1] ~ "p0",
    TRUE ~ new_flag)) %>%
  group_by(id, company) %>%
  mutate(ctr = cumsum(is.na(new_flag) & date != lag(date, default = first(date[is.na(new_flag)])))) %>%
  mutate(new_flag = ifelse(is.na(new_flag), paste0("p", ctr), new_flag)) %>%
  select(-ctr)
```

**Output**

```
      id date       category company flag  new_flag
   <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>   
 1     1 2001-01-04 a        x       rp    rp      
 2     1 2007-09-23 b        x       p1    p1      
 3     1 2008-11-14 b        x       p2    p2      
 4     2 2009-11-13 a        x       nr    nr      
 5     2 2012-07-21 b        y       p0    p0      
 6     2 2014-09-15 b        y       p0    p0      
 7     3 2000-04-01 a        x       rp    rp      
 8     3 2008-07-14 b        x       p1    p1      
 9     3 2008-07-14 b        x       p1    p1      
10     4 2001-03-21 a        x       nr    nr      
11     4 2019-05-23 b        y       p0    p0      
12     4 2019-05-08 b        z       p0    p0      
13     5 2004-07-06 a        x       rp    rp      
14     5 2007-08-12 a        x       rp    rp      
15     5 2011-09-20 b        x       p1    p1      
16     5 2011-09-20 b        x       p1    p1      
17     5 2014-08-15 b        x       p2    p2      
18     5 2014-08-15 b        y       p0    p0
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to write a function to correctly flag the categories based on your conditions. For each group of `id` and `company`, your conditions simplify to three mutually exclusive ones:

- The company has both **a** and **b**; code all **a**s "rp" and **b**s "p1-pn" in chronological order.
- The company only has **a**; code all **a**s "np".
- The company only has **b**; code all **b**s "p0".

Hence, consider the following function

```
flag_category <- function(x, date) {
  out <- character(length(x))
  a <- which(x == "a")
  b <- which(x == "b")
  if (length(a) > 0L && length(b) > 0L) {
    out[a] <- "rp"
    dateb <- date[b]    # get the date where category is "b"
    udateb <- unique(dateb)   # get the unique dates
    out[b] <- paste0("p", rank(udateb)[match(dateb, udateb)])    # `rank` finds the order for each unique date; use `match` to get the positions in `dateb` to which those ranks belong
    return(out)
  }
  if (length(a) > 0L) {
    out[] <- "nr"
    return(out)
  }
  out[] <- "p0"
  out
}
```

Then you can just apply it to each group of `id` and `company`.

```
dfx %>% group_by(id, company) %>% mutate(flag2 = flag_category(category, date))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 6
# Groups:   id, company [9]
      id date       category company flag  flag2
   <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1     1 2001-01-04 a        x       rp    rp   
 2     1 2007-09-23 b        x       p1    p1   
 3     1 2008-11-14 b        x       p2    p2   
 4     2 2009-11-13 a        x       nr    nr   
 5     2 2012-07-21 b        y       p0    p0   
 6     2 2014-09-15 b        y       p0    p0   
 7     3 2000-04-01 a        x       rp    rp   
 8     3 2008-07-14 b        x       p1    p1   
 9     3 2008-07-14 b        x       p1    p1   
10     4 2001-03-21 a        x       nr    nr   
11     4 2019-05-23 b        y       p0    p0   
12     4 2019-05-08 b        z       p0    p0   
13     5 2004-07-06 a        x       rp    rp   
14     5 2007-08-12 a        x       rp    rp   
15     5 2011-09-20 b        x       p1    p1   
16     5 2011-09-20 b        x       p1    p1   
17     5 2014-08-15 b        x       p2    p2   
18     5 2014-08-15 b        y       p0    p0
```